# Javascript Variables - undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Why when I click on a table row, does it alert that row data-attribute as "undefined"?

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {

    alert($(this).data("recordId"))

});
```

Here is the PHP which (successfully) passes the variable of `fee_source_id` into the table row as the data-attribute

```
<table = "all_aifs">
<tr>
    <th><b>Invoice ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Company Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Invoice Date</b></th>
    <th><b>Link</b></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr data-recordId="<?=$row[id];?>"
    class="<?=$row["match"] ? "match" : "";?>">
    <td><?php echo $row[id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[invoice_date]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the comments below, I discovered there was a few errors in the JavaScript code above, as follows:

1. the alert method was calling the `data` element instead of the `attr` element.
2. the parameters for the `attr` method were changed to `("data-recordId")`. (Note: jQuery knows to ignore the first part of this parameter, and so, the `data-` was not included as a parameter.)
3. there was a missing semi-colon at the end of the alert method

### Updated jQuery (this now works)

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {

    alert($(this).attr("data-recordID"));

});
```

**QUESTIONS**:

- I am using jQuery 1.7.2 which supports the `$.on()` and should also support the `.data()` and so, should my original positng which uses the `.data()` method still work? Why is it not working?
- Instead of setting the data-attribute to be "x", since it is exactly equal to the first column of each row in the table, (`fee_source_id`) could I just use the first column/cell in each row of the table instead of the data-attribute which has been passed, to make reference to that record?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? For old versions, use `.attr("data-recordId")` instead.

Comment: your alert misses semicolon!!!!

Comment: Also it could be from `on`. try to replace it with `live`.

Comment: `live` is depricataed. I think it's the semi colon and more importantly, the `.attr("data-recordId")`

Comment: @techfoobar: Seems like he's at least using 1.7+ so `data` should be available afaik.

Comment: @elclanrs - Yeah, since he's using `on()` - Din notice that..

Comment: @techfoobar I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Guys - instead of setting the data-attribute to be "x", since it is exactly equal to the first column of each row in the table, could I just use the first cell in each row of the table instead of the data-attribute to make reference to that record?

Comment: Of course, if they are the same and the data is pure text (is assume this from the name "recordId"), this should work. Use `.text()` to get the raw *textual* representation. The method `data("foo")` works for `data-foo="bar"` in jQuery 1.7+, definitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using jQuery 1.7.2 which supports the `$.on()` and should also support the `.data()` and so, should my original positng which uses the `.data()` method still work? Why is it not working?

If you access data attributes with `.data`, [you're actually reading from jQuery's `data` object](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5), which happens to map cameCased keys to hyphenated keys (`recordId -> record-id`). This means if you rename your attribute to `data-record-id`, you can get it with `.data('record-id')` and `.data('recordId')`. [See a demontration](http://jsbin.com/emeyux/1/edit).

> Instead of setting the data-attribute to be "x", since it is exactly equal to the first column of each row in the table, (`fee_source_id`) could I just use the first column/cell in each row of the table instead of the data-attribute which has been passed, to make reference to that record?

Yes, you can do that with (example included in the same [demo](http://jsbin.com/emeyux/1/edit)):

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var record_id = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    alert(record_id);
});
```